# Model selection with Firth logistic regression

Tags: logistic, model-selection, aic, separation

In a small data set ($n\sim100$ ) that I am working with, several variables give me [perfect prediction/separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/5739). I thus use [Firth logistic regression](https://www.r-bloggers.com/example-8-15-firth-logistic-regression/) to deal with the issue.

If I select the best model by [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) or [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), should I include the Firth penalty term in the likelihood when computing these information criteria?

Comment: Good question! Both are derived assuming maximum-likelihood fits, so you can't use the unpenalized likelihood; but I'm not sure that simply substituting it with the penalized likelihood is the answer.

Comment: Konishi & Kitagawa (1996), "Generalized information criteria in model selection", *Biometrika*, **83**, 4 might be helpful.

Comment: Just for reference, it's [here](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/83/4/875.abstract), but I don't have access -- is that the one where they proposed the trace of information matrix (or something like that) as the penalty term? I remember working with their idea like 15 years ago in mixture modeling.

Comment: It's twice the trace of the ratio of two things, both of which are going to be equal to the information matrix for maximum-likelihood fits and thus give $2p$ as the special case for AIC. (Or something like that - it's going to take me a while to read this.)

Comment: I try to avoid variable selection in general, and in this setting variable selection is particularly complicated.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankHarrell. I am afraid this is unavoidable for me in this project.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why it is unavoidable, since variable selection does not help with the "too many variables, too little sample size" problem?

Comment: Thanks @FrankHarrell -- referee requests, as usual. The kitchen sink regression does not show anything at all, and everybody (both other authors on the paper and the referees) want to see a tight model that would explain *something*.

Comment: That is as bad as it gets.

Comment: Have you considered treating this a Bayesian inference problem?  Firth logistic regression is equivalent to MAP with jeffreys prior.  You could use the fully laplace approximation to evalute marginal likelihoods - which is like an adjusted BIC (similar to AICc)

Comment: maybe dumb question, but if you know what variable is causing perfect separation, why use any other variable at all? Isn't it like having perfect fit?

Comment: @user, Because such variables usually predict only a handful of cases, and that is irreproducible: the true probability for that cell may be close to 90% say but with only two cases in it, you will get two ones 81% of the time.

Comment: Link to download K&K (1996) paper found on Google Scholar, http://bemlar.ism.ac.jp/zhuang/Refs/Refs/kitagawa1996biometrika.pdf

Comment: What did you end up doing for this problem? I would think yes, substitute with the penalised likelihood in AIC since it's part of parameter selection. I can't imagine you could leave it out. I don't know if there are better ways to incorporate it though.

Comment: @Margalit: I don't think this answers the too many variables not enough samples issue.  I think you are suggest ways to try to avoid overfitting.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to justify the use of BIC: you can replace the maximum likelihood with the maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimate and the resulting 'BIC'-type criterion remains asymptotically valid (in the limit as the sample size $n \to \infty$). As mentioned by @probabilityislogic, Firth's logistic regression is equivalent to using a Jeffrey's prior (so what you obtain from your regression fit is the MAP).

The BIC is a pseudo-Bayesian criterion which is (roughly) derived using a Taylor series expansion of the marginal likelihood $$p_y(y) = \int L(\theta; y)\pi(\theta)\mathrm{d} \theta$$ around the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\theta}$. Thus it ignores the prior, but the effect of the latter vanishes as information concentrates in the likelihood.

As a side remark, Firth's regression also removes the first-order bias in exponential families.